# How to fix auto height in css

Tags: html, css

I am using background image working dimension 1400x700, but not working 1392x1403 height not adjustment responsive mode. I need adjust auto height. Could you please solve this issue and attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Add a [repro]! Then the question is, do you want to maintain the aspect ratio of the image and have it cropped? -> `background-size: cover;` or do you want to not crop the image and fill the element? -> `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Answer (score 2):

Have the image maintain its aspect ratio but crop it to fill the entire element: `background-size: cover;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Have the image not maintain its aspect ratio to not crop it but fill the entire element: `background-size: 100% 100%;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 *{
margin:0;
padding:0;
  }
 body{
 height:100vh;
 background-image: url("image_name");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
```

It will not crop your image and will fill the below space.